# Deploy public site and community from sandbox to production org

Tags: deployment

Our requirement is to deploy a public site and community we created from the sandbox to the production org.

If we have to create a new community and public site, we will have to make changes in the page links that are available on the public site.

Is there a process to deploy a public site and community without creating new ones in the production org?

Comment: Public Force.com sites can be deployed using metadata type `CustomSite` - [see answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/370566/2602)

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know.

To keep a Site working in multiple orgs, grab information from the [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) class rather than hard-coding. For example:

> **getPathPrefix()**
>   Returns the URL path prefix of the current site or an
>   empty string if none. For example, if the requested site URL is
>   http://myco.force.com/partners, then /partners is the path prefix. If
>   the current request is not a site request, then this method returns an
>   empty string.