# How to submit a site, its access profile and permissions to production

Tags: change-set

I made a Salesforce Site in a sandbox.

[image]

Salesforce automatically made a user that accesses this site and now I want to put this site and user in production, but I don't know if it's possible. While searching, I noticed that in the list of items that can be added to the change set there is the [Site.com](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.changesets_about_components.htm&type=5).

But, I don't know if this site I'm making and Site.com are the same thing, and if they are, I don't know how to add it to the package changes. I already added the VFPs.

- how do I add the automatically created profile to access the portal?
- Is it possible to send this portal that I made along with the profiles and their permissions to production?
- Or will I have to redo the site/portal in production?

When I say profile, that's the guy I'm referring to:[image]
But the most important for me is to take the object settings:[image]
I don't know if it's possible, and I didn't find anything that helped me on google...

Comment: could you give more details on what you've done? What User are you referring to - the Site Contact? You can also test moving your changes to another sandbox as well to practice.

Comment: I simply searched for "sites" in settings, then clicked on "create", already the user I refer to, I see when I click on the site label>public access settings>assigned users. –

I edited the question, I hope it's easier to understand... anyway thanks for the help @Kris Goncalves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you made the site. If you directly created the site using the Sites in Set up using the new button, then you will have to recreate it in Production or using metadata API (Using tools like Salesforce CLI or workbench), the metadata type is [CustomSite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sites.htm). Changeset does not support CustomSite yet.

While if you generate this site by creating an Experience Cloud Site, then you can use changesets to add site.com, profiles, and permissions to move this. This is also documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_migrate_changesets.htm&type=5).

In your screenshot, it looks like the First 2 sites you created directly and has no Experience Site linked, these two have to be manual recreation or need metadata API.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and also for the links! Helped me a lot @Mohith Shrivastava